# not in na mesma tabela

Tags: sql, pl-sql, oracle12c

Digamos que tenho a tabela `CON_CONTRATOS` e nela tenho `con_customerId`, `con_vencimento` entre outros. E eu preciso fazer um select que me retorne TODOS os contratos de um customer cujo o mesmo só tenha contrato com `con_vencimento not null`. Ou seja, se ele tiver um contrato com con_vencimento null, não retorna nada. Tentei fazer isto utilizando `not in`, porém não obtive sucesso. Tinha tentado desta maneira :

```
SELECT con_customer
FROM con_contratos 
WHERE con_vencimento IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM con_contratos WHERE con_vencimento IS NULL);
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. Por somente o `WHERE con_vencimento IS NOT NULL` não atende seu caso?

Comment: Pq, isso retornaria os contratos que não são nulos, mesmo ele tendo pelo menos 1 nulo, no caso, eu preciso que retorne, apenas se nenhum dos contratos do mesmo for null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa checar se o *customer* possui contratos nulos, da forma que fez está checando toda tabela sem especificar isso:

```
SELECT con_customer
FROM con_contratos C1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM con_contratos C2 
                  WHERE C1.con_customerId = C2.con_customerId
                    AND C2.con_vencimento IS NULL);
```